# CS50 harvard Finance : Issue with code for register

Tags: flask

```
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    else:
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        if not username:
            return apology("Must Give Username")
        try:
            new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hash)
        except:
            return apology("Username already exists")
        if not password:
            return apology("Must Give Password")

        if not confirmation:
            return apology("Must Give Confirmation")

        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("Password Do Not Match")

        hash = generate_password_hash("password")

        try:
            new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hash)
        except:
            return apology("Username already exists")
        session["user_id"] = new_user

        return redirect("/")
```

this is my code for register. When I run check 50 it shows the following problems:

```
register user succeeds and protfolio page is displayed
         expected status 200, not 400
registeration rejects duplicate username
         expected status 200, not 400
```

i tried multipule codes it still isn't working